# complicated query in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

In my model, I have a function to generate a random list of ID's. how to create a query like this in my model?

```
select * from `table`
  where (ID % 1000) = floor(rand() * 1000)
  AND `type`='11'
  order by rand()
  limit 40
```

I know i could use the `query builder` way, but was wondering if there is a way using something like `ABC::model()->findAll()...`

Answer (score 2):

You always can use [`CDbCriteria`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria)

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('`t`.`id` % 1000 = floor(rand() * 1000)');
$criteria->compare('`t`.`type`', 11);
$criteria->order = 'rand()';
$criteria->limit = 40;

ABC::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$model = ABC::model()->findAll(
    array(
       "condition"=>"type = 11 AND (ID % 1000 = floor(rand() * 1000))",
       "order"=>"rand()",
       "limit" => 40
    )
);
```